# Postgres not showing query planning info about constraints checks

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `Ticket` table with a foreign key `event_id` on `Event` table. When  I try to do a simple operation on the `Event` table:

```
delete from event where id > 7
```

and trying to use `explain` over it, it doesn't show that it is scanning sequentially the event_id FK in the `Ticket` table to ensure there are no `Ticket`'s referencing the `Event` table. Why is that?

After cancelling the delete statement postgres logs shows:

```
2017-10-13 14:56:38 PYST CONTEXT:  statement SQL: «SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."ticket" x WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "event_id" FOR KEY SHARE OF x»
2017-10-13 14:56:38 PYST STATEMENT:  delete from event where id > 27879
```

Comment: You are presumably deleting a lot of rows.  That takes time.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Also posted to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/188444/1822

Comment: Ok, thanks, some guy asked there this "Does it show when using explain (analyze, verbose)?"... I have not tried that. Will do that monday